# Read/write /proc/<pid>/mem from java code on Android platform

Tags: java, android, c, bytebuffer, ptrace

I want to read and write memory from ptaced child process (/proc/pid/mem) on Android. Before read/write i attached to process using ptrace (Status=4991, WIFSTOPPED(Status)=true).

```
int lSize = (int) (pAddressEnd - pAddressStart);
ByteBuffer lByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(lSize);
RandomAccessFile lRandomAccessFile = null;
try {
    lRandomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(mFileName, "r");
    lRandomAccessFile.getChannel().read(lByteBuffer, pAddressStart);

    lRandomAccessFile.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
...
```

Sometimes memory access passes correctly, but sometimes it throw exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: pread failed: EIO (I/O error)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: pread failed: EIO (I/O error)
        at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.readImpl(FileChannelImpl.java:315)
        at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:283)
        at test.Process$Mem.readByteBuffer(Process.java:285)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: pread failed: EIO (I/O error)
        at libcore.io.Posix.preadBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.pread(Posix.java:99)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.pread(BlockGuardOs.java:124)
        at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.readImpl(FileChannelImpl.java:305)
        ... 35 more
```

Attempt to write memory always throw exception.

Can I use the method RandomAccessFile.getChannel().read() for reading a memory? And RandomAccessFile.getChannel().write() for writing memory? How use it correct?

Comment: Your question appears to have nothing at all to do with ptrace. People that know how to help you but have no interest in ptrace will ignore your question while people that know ptrace (a C concept that Java, I think, does not support) but not Java random access file usage will come to your question and waste their time till they realize they can't help you. Valid communication / description of your problem is vital and you seem to have failed miserably on your first attempt. I strongly suggest you edit your problem and set the title and content with reasonable clarity for your needs.

Comment: @mah: The question seems reasonable enough to me, particularly given that English obviously isn't their first language. Combining /dev/X/mem with ptrace is a completely standard technique. Also, phrases like 'failed miserably' are possibly not constructive...

Comment: @DavidGiven I think I agree that "failed miserably" was a bit harsh. I still feel though that a question's title needs to at least come close to matching what will be found in it and pre-edit, that was not the case here. While ptrace and reading /dev/X/mem are certainly related, the problem expressed not only has nothing to do with ptrace, ptrace doesn't even appear in it except for the incidental (the process I want to read is ptraced) statement. It's not clear to me (until going to the poster's profile) that English is secondary but that's no excuse for a title that is orthogonal to the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get EIO when trying to read from memory which the child process doesn't have mapped ---  for example, anything around NULL. That's perfectly normal. (See [the mem man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/mem) for more information.) So if you're following broken pointers in the child's address space, you need to be able to handle this.

If you're getting an IO error when you expect the child process' memory to actually exist, that's a bit weirder. There may be some odd interaction between `/dev/X/mem` and ptrace when the child process is stopped. I would suggest investigating `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` as an alternative way to read the child process' memory. It's much slower but potentially more reliable --- if `/dev/X/mem` fails, try `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` and see what it says. I'm assuming you have Java bindings for ptrace.

Comment: Thx for answer. Yes, PTRACE_PEEKDATA and PTRACE_POKEDATA work perfect, but it is so slow for big data. I'm trying to optimize the method. [scanmem](https://code.google.com/p/scanmem/source/browse/trunk/ptrace.c) source code contain this: /* TODO: may use /proc/<pid>/mem here */
bool write_array(pid_t target, void *addr, const void *data, int len)... (This prompted me to modify the code.).I understood the problem. Thx.